# PHP Telegram Bot | How to set automatic welcome? (without /start)

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I created a bot in PHP and added it to my group,

That members of the group could send commands to the bot through the group.

What I want to do now is that once a new user has entered the group
($username has joined the group)

Will appear to him some msg "Welcome $username!..."

Without having to type /start

Until now I have used the Welcome Bot:

https://github.com/jh0ker/welcomebot

But I want to know if there is a possibility to do such a auto welcome msg either through PHP.

like that:

```
if($message == "$username has joined group"){
sendMessage($chatId,"Welcome $username!");}
```

Comment: Sure you can, without a PHP code sample it’s hard to put in words however you can easily create an event listening condition function that when a new user joins trigger a function to send message into chat; it’s absolutely doable (I’ve built a few of these) in PHP you can automate triggers based on events very easy by specifying what the condition event is and what action to fire if it meets the condition, in your case a new user entering the room/connecting or even exiting

Answer (score 0):

You should use new_chat_members

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message

Into message you have a lot od parameters, you should use `new_chat_members` :

new_chat_members :  Array of User   Optional. New members that were added to the group or supergroup and information about them (the bot itself may be one of these members)

```
message.content_types=['new_chat_members']
```